# Error when trying to install windowsazure.mediaservices via nuget

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, azure-media-services

I am trying to develop an android app in C# (Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015) in which I intend to consume the azure media services. In order to do that, I tried to install the nuget package `windowsazure.mediaservices`, but the installation fails, saying

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   Could not install package 'TransientFaultHandling.Core 5.1.1209.1'.
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

For more information, contact the package author. I compile my project using    Android 7.0, and the Target Android Version is 7.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Our current .NET SDK does not support Mono or .NET Core.  We are working on providing an updated SDK this year.  For now, you are going to have to wrap the REST API directly in your application when calling from Mono.

Quick question for clarity though - why are you calling media services directly in your client app and not from a middle tier? Are you planning to distribute your Media Services account credentials inside your application for all users to access? Not advisable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed with Media Services Rest API. This is only a school project.